C++: Template specialization of class member function, differing from another member function only in accepting parameters by reference, not by value
Within template class Bank<T>, my goal is to create an overload for type Account to member function void Bank<T>::makeTransfer(T, T, const double), of signature void Bank<Account>::makeTransfer(Account&, Account&, const double).
That is, makeTransfer function should accept reference parameters when invoked with Accounts, while it should be copying the arguments in for any other type.
What I went with, is creating another makeTransfer<T> function of similar signature, but accepting reference T& arguments instead of T. Then, I added a template specialization to this new function using Account as T.
The MWE below however does not compile successfully, see GDBonline compiler link.
#include <cstdio>
#include <functional>
#include <concepts>

class Account {
public:
  Account() = default;
  Account(const long id, const double balance): _id{id}, _balance{balance} {
    printf("Account no.%ld start balance is %f\n", _id, _balance);
  }

  const long getId() {
    return _id;
  }

  const double getBalance() {
    return _balance;
  }

  void addToBalance(const double sum) {
    _balance += sum;
  }

private:
  long _id;
  double _balance;
};

template<typename T> class Bank {
public:
  void makeTransfer(T from, T to, const double amount) {
    printf("ID %ld -> ID %ld: %f\n", from, to, amount);
  }
  
  void makeTransfer(T& from, T& to, const double amount) {}
};

template<> void Bank<Account>::makeTransfer(Account& from, Account& to, const double amount) {
  printf("ID %ld -> ID %ld: %f\n", from.getId(), to.getId(), amount);

  from.addToBalance(-amount);
  to.addToBalance(amount);
  printf("Account no.%ld balance is now %f\n", from.getId(), from.getBalance());
  printf("Account no.%ld balance is now %f\n", to.getId(), to.getBalance());    
}

int main() {
  // try with fundamental type as T
  Bank<long> bank;
  bank.makeTransfer(1000L, 2000L, 49.95);
  bank.makeTransfer(2000L, 4000L, 20.00);

  // now define a bank with Account instances
  Account a{500, 2600};
  Account b{1000, 10'000};
  Bank<Account> bank2;

  bank2.makeTransfer(a, b, 49.95);
  bank2.makeTransfer(b, a, 20.00);

  //bank2.makeTransfer(std::ref(a), std::ref(b), 49.95);
  //bank2.makeTransfer(std::ref(b), std::ref(a), 20.00);
}

Compiler protests of not being able to pick the correct template instantiation:
main.cpp:58:21: error: call of overloaded ‘makeTransfer(Account&, Account&, double)’ is ambiguous
   58 |   bank2.makeTransfer(a, b, 49.95);
      |   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:31:8: note: candidate: ‘void Bank::makeTransfer(T, T, double) [with T = Account]’
   31 |   void makeTransfer(T from, T to, const double amount) {
      |        ^~~~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:38:17: note: candidate: ‘void Bank::makeTransfer(T&, T&, double) [with T = Account]’
   38 | template<> void Bank<Account>::makeTransfer(Account& from, Account& to, const double amount) {
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~

I tried to inject references explicitly with std::ref, but that did not help.
Using something like std::same_as<T, Account> seems redundant, as all cues for the compiler should already be available in the template specialization.

It doesn't work with longs either, if you try to pass named variables rather than rvalues: long x=1000L, y=2000L; bank.makeTransfer(x, y, 49.95); The problem is not specialization, it's having two member functions with ambiguous signatures.

You can specialize the whole class template instead: template <typename T> class Bank { void makeTransfer(T ...); }; template <> class Bank<Account> { void makeTransfer(Account& ...); }; Though frankly I'm not sure I understand the point of the exercise; it seems like an odd thing to want to do.

@IgorTandetnik: works fine as you suggest

@IgorTandetnik the point of the exercise I think was about having different versions for the same function: one just for rvalue integral types which have no use of references, and the other for more elaborate types. Surprised this cannot be achieved with simple standard template specialization

If you can express the difference between two flavors of types as a trait, you can write void makeTransfer(ValueOrReference_t<T> a, ValueOrReference_t<T> b).  Something like this

@IgorTandetnik neat. But maybe specializing the whole class as you suggested before is more readable

@IgorTandetnik: boost has call_traits for ValueOrReference_t<T>

From printf, valid T parameters are very limited...


From the point of view of any bank, the Account cannot be copied, right? So, it must prevent copies:
  Account(const Account&) = delete;
  Account& operator=(const Account&) = delete;


Update the Bank template
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
class Bank {
 public:
  void makeTransfer(T from, T to, const double amount)
    requires(std::is_copy_constructible_v<T> || std::is_copy_assignable_v<T>)
  {
    printf("ID %ld -> ID %ld: %f\n", from, to, amount);
  }

  void makeTransfer(T& from, T& to, const double amount) {}
};



https://godbolt.org/z/9sEaov3K8

This is a clever way to force the compiler into the right choice. Even better (from my point of view) would be to add a requires (!std::is_same_v<T, Account>) statement to the first makeTransfer function, so Account would be left copyable godbolt link.

..However it feels a little bit of a hack. I know references are just aliases for objects, but still the two functions have different signatures, thus the compiler should be able to pick this up and proceed with the correct template instantiation
